# python json lookups using a value from another search

Tags: python, json

Newbie here, usual apologies.So I am very basic and completely self taught (= learned just by copying code from websites, mostly here).

==> Background <==
Ultimately I'm trying to create a hierarchical display of taskwarrior dependencies. The steps I think I need to complete are:

1. TW export --> JSON
2. JSON import to python
3. find entries where the key 'depends' exists (these are the parent tasks)
4. extract the value(s) in the 'depends' pair (these are the UUID of the child tasks)
5. lookup those values in the imported JSON (to get the child task(s) description)
6. display in a pretty, human readable order

I've gotten stuck on step 5.

==> Question <==
How should I structure the logic of my lookups please?

Many thanks in advance.

wgii

```
import json

inputfile=open('data_file.json', encoding='utf-8')
pydata=json.load(inputfile)

for parent in pydata:
    if "depends" in parent:
        print(parent['description'])
        for child in pydata:
            if child['uuid'] = parent[depends]:
                print(child['description'])
```

--- EDIT --- added error message & numbered the redacted lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/json0.py", line 10, in <module>
    if child['uuid'] == parent[depends]:
NameError: name 'depends' is not defined
```

The json:

```
 [
 {"id":1,"depends":["e6e559c6-742d-4862-9eca-a0f100e1cdb9"],"description":"redacted_1","entry":"20180406T204008Z","modified":"20180406T211650Z","status":"pending","uuid":"842003ce-b52f-4a1c-b6b2-7586c5e5defe","urgency":-4.92877},
 {"id":2,"description":"redacted_2","entry":"20180406T211113Z","modified":"20180406T215713Z","status":"pending","uuid":"e6e559c6-742d-4862-9eca-a0f100e1cdb9","urgency":8.07123},
 {"id":3,"description":"redacted_3","entry":"20180406T211224Z","modified":"20180406T221728Z","status":"pending","uuid":"184c1e8b-acf0-4cf3-b2d5-8130e5cb2cca","urgency":8.07123},
 {"id":4,"description":"redacted_4","due":"20180404T230000Z","entry":"20180406T215603Z","modified":"20180406T222147Z","priority":"H","start":"20180406T222147Z","status":"pending","uuid":"770aa058-ba48-453c-8070-6bb32279e7c8","urgency":22.0712},
 {"id":5,"description":"redacted_5","entry":"20180406T223551Z","modified":"20180406T223951Z","start":"20180404T230000Z","status":"pending","uuid":"69e44b6e-0a55-48d7-b659-352753ae19ae","annotations":[{"entry":"20180406T223716Z","description":"now"}],"urgency":4.87123},
 {"id":6,"description":"redacted_6","entry":"20180420T123738Z","modified":"20180420T123738Z","status":"pending","uuid":"0c470063-92ae-4893-b7de-bd9b9f94fb04","urgency":0}
 ]
```

Some System Info:
xubuntu 16.04
thonny 2.1.16
python 3.6.4

----- EDIT 2 --------------- Following Prateek's Help -------------

ok I'm getting closer:

```
import json

inputfile=open('data_file.json', encoding='utf-8')
pydata=json.load(inputfile)

ID_descr = {}
for z in pydata:
    ID_descr[z['uuid']]= [z['description']]

for parent in pydata:
    if "depends" in parent:   
        print(parent['description'])
        childNo=(parent['depends'])
        print(childNo)
        print(ID_descr[(childNo)])
```

Output + Error Msg:

```
redacted_1
['e6e559c6-742d-4862-9eca-a0f100e1cdb9']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/json0.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(ID_descr[(childNo)])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

tried several variations of the last line but can't figure out how to get the ID_descr dict lookup to work with the 'variable'.

eg. with / without brackets & with / without " " or ' ' - no help

eg. I tried to stringify ... `childNo=str(parent['depends'])`

but that just gives me a diffn error: `KeyError: "['e6e559c6-742d-4862-9eca-a0f100e1cdb9']"`

Comment: Is it school assignment? Looks like so.Stuck as in? is there any error whats the output?

Comment: Why that's very generous of you. No, not an assignment, unfortunately school, university and formal education are all a distant memory. Its a very real need/ desire to see my task list in a hierarchical order. Will try to paste the error msg, can't believe I didn't think of including it. Also my code uses a "==" not a "=" in the if test. I just tried the variation cos it sometimes works in bash.

Answer (score 0):

json is converted to dictionary in `pydata` To get inner values you need to parse the dictionary as you want.

1. First save all child IDs in a list or dictionary
2. Print description of those child ids.

### Code

```
child_task_dic = dict()
# Get all child ids from JSON
for parent in pydata:
        # print('id ' + str(parent['id']) + ':' + parent['description'])
        if 'depends' in parent:
            child_task_dic[parent['id']]= parent['depends']

for k,v in child_task_dic.items():
    print('Parent task id : ' + str(k))
    for y in pydata:
        if y['uuid'] in v:
            print('\t' + 'Child task id ' + y['uuid'])
            print('\tStatus : ' + y['description'])
```

#### Output

```
{1: ['e6e559c6-742d-4862-9eca-a0f100e1cdb9']}
Parent task id : 1
    Child task id e6e559c6-742d-4862-9eca-a0f100e1cdb9
    Status : redacted
```

Comment: realized earlier answer dint match OP's requirement , edited

Comment: Man Prateek, That's some other level shizzle !!  I saw your first reply and realised I need a uuid:description dict; but I kid you not the first time I used a dict was about 3 hours ago so I had no chance of writing the dict. ... but ... the thing with two iterables at once, k and v, is hurting my brain. I'll get up in the morning and try to grok it. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: I thought simple list would be fine for your requirement, but what if there are lot of `primary` tasks which you wanna keep track of(look-up) , so this one is better. you can as many details as you want but primary id and child ids in dict is more than enough

Comment: other level shizzle?!? even with tongue in cheek that phrase dates me to about waynes world or bill & teds ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm getting closer.

- added to original post cos I can't figure out the formatting commands

Comment: What do you mean ?